# How to use if else statements inside a try and except condition to find whether a not a number is positive, negative, or zero?

Tags: python, if-statement, except

```
def algop(num):
    try:
        if num == 0:
            return "The number is neither positive nor negative"
    except:   
        sally = num + 1
        if num - sally == -1:
           return int(num), str("is positive")
        else:
           return int(num), str("Is negative")

print(algop(10))
```

The answer I get is "none". How can I get this to work?

Comment: Just remove the `try`/`except`?

Comment: Also, why not use `< 0` and `> 0`? The `sally` variable doesn't seem to make any sense. You are effectively testing `-1 == -1`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Please repeat your materials on `try-except` so that you understand their function and when to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `try` and `except`, they are for error handling. Instead try:

```
def algop(num):
    if num == 0:
        return "The number is neither positive nor negative"
    sally = num + 1
    if num - sally == -1:
        return int(num), str("is positive")
    else:
        return int(num), str("Is negative")

print(algop(10))
```

Also you don't need to do that code for checking positive or negative, just do `<` and `>`, also you could just do f-strings:

```
def algop(num):
    if num == 0:
        return "The number is neither positive nor negative"
    if num > 0:
        return f'{num} is positive'
    else:
        return f'{num} is negative'

print(algop(10))
```

Both codes output:

```
10 is positive
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only use the `Try: except:` if your script stops due to an error ;)

```
def algop(num):
  if num == 0:
    return "The number is neither positive nor negative"
  elif num > 0:
    return str(num) + "is positive"
  else:
    return str(num) + "Is negative"

print(algop(10))
```